hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation fails to install Sonar
I'm using the SonarQube Scanner plugin from Jenkins to install sonarqube scanner in a server throught a pipeline. The pipeline pull sonarscanner from an Artifactory, and it get sonarscanner well. The problem is instead unzip the folder in the same folder of the plugin or the .sonar, it unzip the project in another one. And when sonar scanner will make his analysis can't know this dir.
I ask if someone knows or how can I said to the plugin where I want to make the install or why this happens and I can solve the problem? cause I don't want to use the null dir in my pipeline, I want a generic one.
